# No $L = 0$; $S = 0$ states of Deuteron. Is this due to internal $np$-scattering?

Tags: angular-momentum, nuclear-physics, hydrogen

Quick question regarding the L = 0;  S = 0 states of Deuteron.  In my notes I have stated that the state is unbound by 60keV np scattering.

Am I right in saying this is the internal scattering of the nucleons, and this nucleus is so loosely bound that it simply dissociates under the inevitable internal scattering of the nucleus?

Answer (score 1):

No. The state is simply not bound. Being bound has a clear interpretation. If it was (even loosely) bound, the nucleus would be stable with respect to a particle emission. It could/may decay via weak interaction, though.

You can observe the state in a scattering experiment, the state is called rather a virtual state (a state with a negative binding energy). Check first few sentences from here http://www.phy.ohiou.edu/~elster/phys735/extras/Ma_virtual_d_levels.pdf

One can also think about a resonance - particles, when meeting at the proper energy - are caught in a resonant system and stay there somewhat (much) longer, than is a usual during their pass.Consult also http://electron6.phys.utk.edu/qm2/modules/m7/resonances.htm